# WAMP "Unable to load dynamic library php_intl.dll"

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I just bought a Surface Pro 4 and installed WAMP on it.

But it keeps giving me an error;

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "..../php_intl.dll" - The specified module could not be found.**

But when I searched through the directory, the file is there. I've the same WAMP version installed on my desktop and work laptop (both Windows 10) and they all worked fine out the box. I've tried searching and following some of the help online but none of them worked: reinstalling wamp and copying icu files to apache folder.

A step-by-step process would be appreciated as I'm kinda new to WAMP. Thanks.

Comment: edit `php.ini` (left click  wampmanager icon -> PHP -> php.ini) and add: `extension=c:/wamp/path/to/php extension dir/php_intl.dll`

Comment: @Thomas: obviously that's already there, just with the wrong path, or the extension's not present at all.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/unable-to-load-or-find-php-extension-php_intl-dll

Comment: @CallMeBob tried that but complains "deplister.exe is not recognised"

Comment: @DevITper: At which step ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a minor bug in the WAMPServer install.

It can be corrected very simply, all from the wampmanager menus like this

```
(left click) wampmanager icon -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9
```

Just click the version number `2.4.9` or whatever version number you have currently selected.

This will cause wampmanager to rebuild the SYMLINKS in `\wamp\apache\apache{version}\bin` and then restart Apache.

*Also undo everything that `Dr. Z` suggested, I am afraid it's all bad advice.*

Answer (score 1):

Installing "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4" from  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the php_intl extension, which is in 
{ (left click) wampmanager icon(W) in system tray -> PHP -> PHP extensions -> php_intl }

Answer (score 0):

I had "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015" installed and it didn't work.

Installing "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015, 2017 y 2019" from [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads#section-2) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After verifying your extensions, environmental variables and everything works fine but facing same problem, go ahead

Installing Latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribution from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#section-2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32026101)