# Xdebuger doesn't stop on breakpoint

Tags: php, xdebug

I am new to php and recently I put xdebug for php and work with it fine, but yesterday xdebug didn't stop in my program at breakpoint.

I opened cmd and write php -v and I receive this message:
[[image]

The weird part is that the same debugger works fine on xampp but not on wamp...
Any solutions? I search for the solution and no clue..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WAMP "Unable to load dynamic library php\_intl.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723928/wamp-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-intl-dll)

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that you can spot from the screen you posted is error message about php_xdebug.dll extension failed to be loaded. Without this extension loaded properly xdebug cannot work.

Maybe this docs can help you fix loading the lib: https://xdebug.org/docs/install#configure-php

Comment: Ty for your answer, I did the first step on the "tutorial" (php --ini) and received this error:
The procedure entry point zend_get_parameters_array_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.15\ext\php_xdebug.dll.

Any idea what should I do now?

Comment: Hi, I haven't encountered this kind of error yet, but this one looks similar, cos it looks like you have some mismatch in versions of PHP and xdebug lib.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75788629/php-8-1-with-xdebug-symbol-not-found-in-flat-namespace-zend-get-parameters-a.

Comment: I managed to move all my project to xampp and now I don't need to resolve the debugger anymore. Thank you for answers!

Comment: Nice! Wish you all the best with PHP ;)